# Sending Image with Micronaut Declarative Http client MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA not working

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-client

I am using Micronaut declarative client to communicate among other microservice as below

```
@Client(id="feteBirdProduct", path = "/product")
public interface IProductClient extends IProductOperation {
}
```

Controller method

```
@Controller("/product")
public class ProductController implements IProductOperation {
    @Override
    public Maybe<HttpResponse<?>> post(Publisher<CompletedFileUpload> files, ProductViewModel model) {
        LOG.info(String.format("Controller --> Creating new product"));
        return iProductManager.Create(model).flatMap(item -> {
                    if (item != null)
                        return Maybe.just(HttpResponse.created(item, new URI(item.id())));
                    else
                        return Maybe.just(HttpResponse.serverError());
                }
        );
    }
}
```

IProductOperation interface

```
public interface IProductOperation {
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Post
    @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
    Maybe<HttpResponse<?>> post(@NotBlank Publisher<CompletedFileUpload> files, @Body ProductViewModel model);
}
```

**API Gateway controller**

```
@Controller("/api/${api.version:v1}/product")
public class ApiGatewayProductController implements IProductOperation {
@Override
    public Maybe<HttpResponse<?>> post(@NotBlank Publisher<CompletedFileUpload> files, @Body ProductViewModel model){
        return this.iProductClient.post(files, model);
    }
}
```

When I am making a request keep getting the below logs

```
DEBUG i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Sending HTTP POST to http://localhost:8081/product
22:06:42.631 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Content-Type: application/json
22:06:42.631 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Accept: multipart/form-data
22:06:42.631 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkMzRjE0RTFCRjAzRjhDNzAxRDEwNzZBRjEwNDJBNThBIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.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.ECioDhGTibg9KvJqxK6daGr5iSdMYIzSp3SGSmhSO8cLDwLs1h6K-hhlGjeutBkNQSD8i65LsSjmBrFL9QQbOE58UuHlHySZAY0Sf8_L0_Yx5tisopIuSKyhjtlXElmWZHs3ay4AxcBaGNyiQ0fvxI3SqH6W1TuMLIAr9Dg66GSESXrjWBi-goPJoAj0USSw_QWoJi9CHArIs63NTIanc9lvQJWPlO9TxVqiWm49aq5e1RJQfZKU4uk3i6cExYQDXqoMhg9GBzqrlw1HUBb1EttsRoQR94jCEl5XrRZQuSPIhxdjOrW50W2bxwrvfYXheqj0D8wmcEwD8HGo03WOMg
22:06:42.631 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - X-B3-TraceId: 8b177f888c372156
22:06:42.631 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - X-B3-SpanId: 3cce7450e87bd8b6
22:06:42.631 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - X-B3-ParentSpanId: 8b177f888c372156
22:06:42.631 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - X-B3-Sampled: 1
22:06:42.631 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - host: localhost:8081
22:06:42.631 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - connection: close
22:06:42.631 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - content-length: 46
22:06:42.631 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Request Body
22:06:42.631 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - ----
22:06:42.631 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - {"id":"sdsdf","productOptionViewModel":"SIZE"}
22:06:42.631 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - ----
DEBUG i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Received response 403 from http://localhost:8081/product
22:06:42.645 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - connection: close
22:06:42.645 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Response Body
22:06:42.645 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - ----
22:06:42.645 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - 
22:06:42.645 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - ----
22:06:42.645 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Full HTTP response received an empty body
22:06:42.645 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Unable to convert response body to target type class java.lang.String
```

CURL

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/product" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "id=" -F "productOptionViewModel=SIZE" -F "files=@bird.png;type=image/png"
```

If I remove `Publisher<CompletedFileUpload>` from the controller, the end point is working fine.

Comment: The log says 403, are you missing any authentication header to token

Comment: Can you show the signature of the abstract method in `IProductOperation` which is being invoked?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown updated question with more code

Comment: @silentsudo I marked the method @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS) it should not check the security rule.

Comment: Is it because of Content-Type: application/json ??

Comment: This need to be replace with Multipart Client Uploads https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#clientUploads. Any idea how can I achieve with declarative client

Comment: think `Publisher<CompletedFileUpload>` is blank as you can see in the last line 'Full HTTP response received an empty body'. Or received an empty object.

Comment: @Raghuveer But I have passed files.

Comment: @San Jaisy So that means for some reason the file is not reaching your service. Check  if ((files.getFilename() == null || files.getFilename().equals("")))

Comment: @Raghuveer - This is the issue with declarative client I need to change the code as per https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#clientUploads. I am not sure how to do with declarative client